# o que significa "As preocupações acabaram com ele"

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Gostaria de saber o que diz a segunda frase, em negrito, abaixo:

> Ele não é mais o mesmo. **As preocupações acabaram com ele**.

Tem um significado positivo ou negativo? Está dizendo que "os problemas acabaram e agora a vida dele é melhor" ou "por causa dos problemas ele não é o cara legal que ele era antes"?

Comment: Significaria que "os problemas acabaram e agora a vida dele é melhor" se fosse **As preocupações dele acabaram**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É "acabar com" no [sentido](https://dicionario.priberam.org/acabar) de "dar cabo de", "**destruir**".

Ele pode não ter deixado de ser um cara legal (se ele o era), mas em algum sentido está destruído -- talvez sem forças, ou sem esperanças ou ambições; ou ainda desinteressado, ou ansioso, ou amedrontado, ou irritadiço, etc., de uma forma que ele não costumava ser.

Answer (score 1):

"Os problemas acabaram com ele." É uma figura de linguagem. Significa que ele tem passado por tantos problemas que afetaram seu comportamento ao ponto de "não ser mais o mesmo", ou seja, ele tem agido de forma diferente da que ele costuma agir. Muitas pessoas enfrentam tantos problemas ficam com depressão, tristes, desanimadas, desesperadas.